# Ember views can't find precompiled handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have precompiled my handlebars templates, but ember can no longer find them where referencing them like this:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName: "application"
```

I get this error:

Uncaught Error: < App.ApplicationView:ember390 > - Unable to find template "application".

It works when I reference the template like this:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend
   template: Handlebars.templates["application"]
```

..but I'd like to know why I can't do it the first way

Comment: Do you have a template created like <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">some content ...</script> in your html?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think Ember searches at `Ember.TEMPLATES` collection, so perhaps your should compile and store the templates into this collection rather than `Handlebars.templates` collection. I'm saying this because if you do `Em.TEMPLATES["somename"] = Em.Handlebars.compile("some template")` you'll be able to get it by name as in your first script, so perhaps you should just add another step in your pipeline to transfer to `Em.TEMPLATES` instead